# Finding Lyapunov function for particular system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lyapunov-functions

I am trying to find Lyapunov function for $$\begin{cases}\dot{t} = y\\\dot{y} = t^2-t\end{cases}$$
I tried common examples but, maybe I was wrong in my computations, couldn't derive anything.

Could you help? Is there any approaches that cover some easy situations like this one (when variables are "separated")?

Comment: The question needs clarification. You want to a find a Lyapunov function foe what? The system has two equilibrium points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please allow me to write $(x,y)$ instead of $(t,y)$.

Any system of the form
$$
\dot x = y
,\quad
\dot y = -V'(x)
$$
(which is equivalent to the Newton-type second-order ODE $\ddot x = -V'(x)$ where $V(x)$ is the potential energy)
is a Hamiltonian system generated by $H(x,y) = \tfrac12 y^2 + V(x)$,
so $H$ is a constant of motion (and thus also a *weak* Lyapunov function in some neighbourhood of the origin, if it happens to have a local minimum at the origin, like in this case where $H(x,y) = \tfrac12 y^2 + \tfrac12 x^2 - \tfrac13 x^3$).